# How to make a ButtonSegment active/selected of a SegmentedButton programmatically?

Tags: flutter

I have the following `SegmentedButton` ([Material3 docs](https://m3.material.io/components/segmented-buttons/specs)):

```
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SegmentedButton<MenuOptions>(
      
      style: ButtonStyle(
        backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.resolveWith<Color?>(
          (Set<MaterialState> states) {
            if (states.contains(MaterialState.selected)) {
              return Color.fromARGB(255, 196, 238, 148);
            }
            return null; // Use the component's default.
          },
        ),
      ),
      showSelectedIcon: false,
      segments: const <ButtonSegment<MenuOptions>>[
        ButtonSegment<MenuOptions>(
            value: MenuOptions.manage,
            label: Text('Manage'),
            icon: Icon(Icons.precision_manufacturing_rounded)),
        ButtonSegment<MenuOptions>(
            value: MenuOptions.reports,
            label: Text('Reports'),
            icon: Icon(Icons.paste)),
      ],
      selected: <MenuOptions>{menuOptionsView},
      onSelectionChanged: (Set<MenuOptions> newSelection) {
        setState(() {
          if (newSelection.first == MenuOptions.manage) {
            //...
          } else {
            //...
          }
          menuOptionsView = newSelection.first;
        });
      },
    );
  }
```

I need make a `ButtonSegment` active/selected based on some criteria. `selected` property of SegmentedButton is just the view to show on a selected option.
E.g
Say we pass a bool parameter into this class, so based on that boolean, I need to the first `ButtonSegment` to be active/selected, and if the boolean parameter is false, then I need the second `ButtonSegment` to be active/selected